# Outlook 2013: New Meeting Request - This meeting is not in the Calendar folder for this account

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, google-calendar, meeting-request

I highlight a child calendar in Outlook 2013 and create a New Meeting Request. When I click Send, I get the following prompt.

[image: not in calendar folder]

This message is appearing because Outlook 2013 is assuming I am sending the Meeting Request for a child calendar and responses will not be tallied.

[image: In Folder]

In Google Calendar, whenever you create a new event, there is a drop down for all the different calendars you can select.

[image: Google Calendar drop down]

Is there a way for me to change the Meeting Request so that it points to a parent calendar, thus removing the prompt and receiving tallied responses?

Title Bar: Microsoft Outlook
This meeting is not in the Calendar folder for this account.
Responses to this meeting will not be tallied.

Do you want to send anyway?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, this is expected Outlook behaviour.  Outlook will only tally results for a meeting that exists in it's own default calendar, regardless of whether you have access to the other calendar.

If you want it to work with other calendars (including delegated calendars) you need to login to Google Calendar in the browser, and update the meeting there.

Comment: Or just use Android or iOS that has superior integration with Exchange ActiveSync and Google Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

In the meeting request in Outlook 2016, you can use "File" > "Move to Folder" to move the meeting to the desired calendar.

Comment: For Mac, there is a dropdown just above the event title where you can switch calendars.